# Getting the tag of grid-view item? finding tag by position of the grid-view item?

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I have two Gridviews, Gridview1 and Gridview2. The gridview1 contains drawable images and gridview2 contains nothing.

Whenever the user picks up an image from gridview1 and places the image into gridview2 then the image will be placed into the gridview2.

I want to check the tag of the present placed item with the tag of already placed items (if images are already present in gridview2).

How can I find the tags of the other images? In gridview2 OnItemClickListener we have view but it refers to the current clicked image only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally myself i got the answer for my question.Thank you for all who gave their valuable suggestions.

> i saved the tag of a item of grid-view1 in a variable and used the same variable in the grid-view2 and i set that tag to the current grid-view2's item.so my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the gridview you can get the adapter behind it by calling `getAdapter()`, then from your adapter you should be able to iterate the itmes and read the tags.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer mate.but where to store this g2.getAdapter()